# Optimizacion de query SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una query grande que ejecuto en oracle pero tarda mucho tiempo en obtener resultados, alguien me puede ayudar a revisar y tal vez optimizar mi quer, por favor.

La parte donde se queda colgada mi query es la condicion:

> ```
>            AND A.NOMBRE_PLAZA IN
>                    (SELECT DISTINCT NOMBRE_PLAZA (T.ID_PLACES)
>                       FROM CAT_CAS  C
>                            INNER JOIN AMS_PLACES T
>                                ON T.SUBZONE = C.SUBZONE
>                      WHERE NUMDELEGACION = 1)
> ```

```
SELECT AA.DEC,
       AA.RED              AS RED,
       AA.ID_CUSTOMER      AS "Cliente",
       AA.RFC,
       AA.ID_ACCOUNT       AS "Cta",
       AA.SERIE,
       AA.FOLIO,
       AA.ID_CARD          AS Folio,
       AA.FECHA_C      AS "Fecha",
       AA.HORA_C       AS "Hora",
       AA.PLAZA,
       AA.TRAM,
       AA.CAR,
       AA.TARIFA           AS "Importe Bruto",
       AA.DESCUENTO        AS "Descuento",
       AA.AMOUNT_CALC      AS "Importe",
       CC.ABBREVIATION     AS "Clase"
  FROM (SELECT A.DEC,
               DES_RED (RFC_EMISOR)
                   AS RED,
               CASE
                   WHEN (A.SERIE = 'CTPA' OR A.SERIE = 'CTUP')
                   THEN
                       TO_CHAR (110316)
                   ELSE
                       A.ID_CUSTOMER
               END
                   ID_CUSTOMER,
               A.RFC_RECEPTOR
                   AS RFC,
               CASE
                   WHEN (A.SERIE = 'CTPA' OR A.SERIE = 'CTUP')
                   THEN
                       TO_CHAR (0000126667)
                   ELSE
                       A.ID_ACCOUNT
               END
                   ID_ACCOUNT,
               A.SERIE,
               A.FOLIO,
               A.ID_CARD,
               TO_CHAR (A.DT_TRANS_DATE_TS, 'DD/MM/RRRR')
                   AS FECHA_CRUCE,
               TO_CHAR (A.DT_TRANS_DATE_TS, 'HH24:MM:SS')
                   AS HORA_CRUCE,
               A.NOMBRE_PLAZA
                   AS PLAZA,
               CASE
                   WHEN        A.TCAR = 'DESCONOCIDA'
                           AND A.TCAR <> ''
                        OR A.TCAR = 'Desconocida'
                   THEN
                       NOMBRE_TRAMO (A.ID_PLACES)
                   ELSE
                       A.TCAR
               END
                   AS TRAMO,
               A.ID_PLACES
                   AS CAR,
               CASE
                   WHEN A.SERIE IN ('NTUP', 'NTTP', 'NTTP') THEN -(A.TARIFA)
                   ELSE A.TARIFA
               END
                   AS TARIFA,
               CASE
                   WHEN A.SERIE IN ('NTUP', 'NTTP', 'NTTP')
                   THEN
                       -(A.DESCUENTO)
                   ELSE
                       A.DESCUENTO
               END
                   AS DESCUENTO,
               CASE
                   WHEN A.SERIE IN ('NTUP', 'NTTP', 'NTTP')
                   THEN
                       -(A.AMOUNT_CALC)
                   ELSE
                       A.AMOUNT_CALC
               END
                   AS AMOUNT_CALC,
               A.SEQ_TRANSIT,
               A.CLASE
          FROM T_TRAZ_X  A
               INNER JOIN TCTROLDEC B
                   ON A.ID_INVOICE = B.ID_INVOICE AND A.DEC = B.DEC
               INNER JOIN AMS_CON C
                   ON A.RFC_EMISOR = C.CIF_COMPANY
               LEFT OUTER JOIN AMS_CUSTOMER D
                   ON D.ID_CUSTOMER = A.ID_CUSTOMER
         WHERE    TO_DATE ('03/11/2018', 'DD/MM/RRRR')
               AND TRUNC (a.DT_TRANS_DATE_TS) >=TO_DATE ('23/10/2018', 'DD/MM/RRRR')  AND TRUNC (a.DT_TRANS_DATE_TS) <= TO_DATE ('03/11/2018', 'DD/MM/RRRR')
               AND A.NOMBRE_PLAZA IN
                       (SELECT DISTINCT NOMBRE_PLAZA (T.ID_PLACES)
                          FROM CAT_CAS  C
                               INNER JOIN AMS_PLACES T
                                   ON T.SUBZONE = C.SUBZONE
                         WHERE NUMDELEGACION = 1)
               AND CASE
                       WHEN    A.RED_TRAN = ''
                            OR A.RED_TRAN = NULL
                            OR A.RED_TRAN = 'DESCONOCIDO'
                            OR A.RED_TRAN = '0'
                       THEN
                           0
                       ELSE
                           TO_NUMBER (
                               REPLACE (
                                   SUBSTR (A.RED_TRAN,
                                           INSTR (A.RED_TRAN, '(') + 1,
                                           INSTR (A.RED_TRAN, ')')),
                                   ')',
                                   ''))
                   END =
                   2
               AND A.SERIE NOT IN ('FTUP', 'NTUP')
               AND ROWNUM <= 500000) AA
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TRZ_QUERY.AMS_TOTAL_CATEGORY CC
           ON NVL (AA.CLASE, 0) = CC.ID_TOTAL_CATEGORY
```

Comment: PAra poder ayudarte, necesitariamos ver el explain plan, las estructuras de las tablas, y los indices. Asi como tambien la cantidad de datos involucrados. Lo unico que podriamos hacer asi como esta es tirar tips si encontramos algo raro a simple vista, pero eso no asegura que la query vaya a funcionar mas rapido.

Comment: @gbianchi tal vez los tips no vendrian mal, miestras recopilo toda la informacion ya que son bastantes tablas

Comment: Como primera medida, estaria bueno separar este query en todos los querys que hace (que son muchos) y verificar los tiempos de cada uno

Comment: @gbianchi la parte donde queda colgada mi query es en la condición después del where principal en  " AND A.NOMBRE_PLAZA IN... " que podría hacer?

Comment: Podrias eliminar ese distinct usando una vista materializada con los resultados de esa consulta, no se que sentido tiene eso ahi, es como raro hacer un in a una tabla con distinct)...

Comment: El distinct no creo que haga gran diferencia. Por otro lado, tal vez afecte el uso de funciones ya que no podemos ver la definición de las mismas para poder decir si se nota algún problema. El CASE en el WHERE también podría ser un problema. Se podría quedar como `REPLACE (SUBSTR (A.RED_TRAN, INSTR (A.RED_TRAN, '(') + 1,INSTR (A.RED_TRAN, ')')),')','')) = '2'`.

Comment: ¿El problema es únicamente a nivel de tiempo? ¿Cuánto es lento en segundos? ¿La consulta si te devuelve los resultados correctos? ¿O es tan tardado que se queda colgada?

Comment: ¿Cuánto se tarda y cuántos registros trae la subconsulta que identificaste si la ejecutas por aparte?

Comment: @JYass son 11 registros que trae la subconsulta, la primera vez que se ejecuto tardo 133 ms y la segunda vez 77 ms, toda la query  tarda mas de 15 min, pero se detecto que es por esta subconsulta